# Infinite while loop in Python, but only when 1 is the target value

Tags: python, while-loop

I've just started learning Python and thought a simple Collatz conjecture program would be a fun project to start with. The idea is to print every step, followed by a total number of steps taken.

Problem is that I can't prevent this code from going into an infinite loop, but only if I use `while x!=1`. I can replace with `while x!=2` and then it stops at 2 as expected. I'm struggling to understand what's so special about the number 1 here.

Here's the code:

```
x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
steps=int(0)

while x!=1:

    if  x%2==0:
        x=int(x/2)
        steps=(steps+1)
        print(x)

    if  x%2!=0:
        x=((x*3)+1)
        steps=(steps+1)
        print(x)

print("Steps:",steps)
```

Comment: You should have used `else` - think about the flow through a loop iteration if `x == 2` at the start of it. Write it out on paper or use e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/ if you can't visualise it in your head.

Comment: It is not just 1, try replacing it with `x != 3` and you will find the same behavior. It happens whenever you are using an odd number.

Comment: because when the code hits the second `if`, the first `if` has changed the value of `x` and vice versa. when `x` is 1 the `if`s changes its value to 4, 2, 1 and the loop continues

Answer (score 1):

It is not just 1, try replacing it with `x != 3` and you will find the same behavior. It happens whenever you are using an odd number.

Whenever it hits the first condition, the value of `x` is changed, and then it again hits the second condition. You probably want to put that into an `else`, to make sure that only one `if` is executed at a time!

Let's assume that `x = 5` at first. It hits the second condition, becomes 16, then hits the first, becomes 8, then 4, then 2, then 1. Only this time, after `x = 1`, it *also* hits the second condition, which changes its value back to 4. And so the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

the while loop will cause problems when x=1. Why not try a for loop and enumerate to track the loop number? for example

```
x = int(input('enter your number'))

for n, i in enumerate(range(x)):

    print('x: {}'.format(x))

    if x % 2 == 0:
        x /= 2

    else:
        x = x * 3 + 1

    if x == 1:
        break

print('steps: {}, x: {}'.format(n, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your codes. For example write 12 to the input section, 9 steps later x's value will be equal to "1" and the loop will be finished when x=1.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
steps = int(0)
while x>1:
    if x!=1:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = int(x / 2)
            steps = (steps + 1)
            print(x)
        else:
            x = ((x * 3) + 1)
            steps = (steps + 1)
            print(x)
print("Steps:",steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses, I hadn't thought to test other odd numbers (feeling especially dumb for that) or to follow an 'if' with an 'else'. Based on some of the answers here, I did manage to get a working program:

```
x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
steps=int(0)

while x!=1:

    if  x%2==0:
        x=int(x/2)

    else: x=((x*3)+1)

    steps=(steps+1)
    print(x)

print("Steps:",steps)
```

However, I'll be trying out the other methods suggested. It's all valuable for me at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `x` should be treated separately when it becomes `1`. If you input `1`, the `steps` would be 0, and it should be `1`.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
steps = 0
while x > 0:
    if x == 1:
        if steps ==0:
            steps += 1
        break
    if x%2 == 0:
        x = x/2
        print(int(x))
    else: 
        x = 3*x + 1
        print(int(x))
    steps += 1
    
print("steps =", str(steps))
```